# problems with overload resolution and operator<< for templated types - part 2

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, overload-resolution

Given the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace has_insertion_operator_impl {
    typedef char no;
    typedef char yes[2];

    struct any_t {
        template <typename T>
        any_t(T const&);
    };

    no operator<<(ostream const&, any_t const&);

    yes& test(ostream&);
    no   test(no);

    template <typename T>
    struct has_insertion_operator {
        static ostream& s;
        static T const&      t;
        static bool const    value = sizeof(test(s << t)) == sizeof(yes);
    };
}

template <typename T>
struct has_insertion_operator : has_insertion_operator_impl::has_insertion_operator<T> {};

template <class T>
typename enable_if<has_insertion_operator<T>::value, string>::type stringify(const T& in) {
    stringstream stream;
    stream << in;
    return stream.str();
}

template <class T>
typename enable_if< ! has_insertion_operator<T>::value, string>::type stringify(const T&) {
    return "{?}";
}

// ======= OVERLOADS PROVIDED BY THE USER =======

template<typename T, typename T2>
struct myType { T data; T2 op; };

template<typename T, typename T2>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, const myType<T, T2>&) { s << "myType"; return s; }

template<typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, const vector<T>&) { s << "vector<T>"; return s; }

template<typename T, typename A>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, const vector<T, A>&) { s << "vector<T, A>"; return s; }

int main() {
    myType<int, float> a;   cout << stringify(a) << endl; // prints "myType"
                            cout << stringify(6) << endl; // prints "6"
    vector<int> v(5);       cout << stringify(v) << endl; // prints "{?}"

    return 0;
}
```

Why does the template `myType<>` get stringified but the templated `vector<>` type doesn't?

For the `vector<>` type I get the default `{?}` stringification but I clearly want one of the overloads at the bottom to be called - just like with `myType<>`

**EDIT:**

The actual question here is *Why is `has_insertion_operator<vector<int>>` false?*

I also need this in C++98

And the `operator<<` overloads should be supplied after `stringify()` - like with `myType<>`

Comment: It is obvious why the vector is not stringified. The question can be simplified to "Why is `has_insertion_operator<vector<int>>` false?"

Comment: @user2079303: What's "obvious" about it? There's a `ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, const vector<T>&)` right there.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well actually he is right - it is the trait's fault - it drives the ```enable_if<>``` and the SFINAE

Comment: @onqtam: There's nothing "obvious" about that. I think user2079303 didn't realise the OP has already attempted to create their own `operator<<` to match.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it is obvious that the overload is not used because it is disabled by `enable_if<has_insertion_operator<T>::value, string>::type`. What is not obvious is **why**  `has_insertion_operator<T>::value` is false, despite `ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, const vector<T>&)`. Hence my suggested simplification of the question.

Comment: @user207 Oh, I see, you're nitpicking about the wording of the question. Okay.

Comment: Why do you need `operator<<` in `has_insertion_operator_impl`? Remove it and it will give you the result you expect

Comment: @ixSci this is a fallback operator...

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I think ixSci meant to remove the namespace - not the fallback operator

Comment: @ixSci WTF! It worked when I removed the namespace!!! Thanks! Post an answer and you'll get some sweet stack overflow credits! Also go answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37121425/problems-with-overload-resolution-and-operator-for-templated-types) and I'll accept you answer there too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the lookup and I will provide my understanding.

When you call the `operator<<` in your `has...` struct argument dependent lookup kicks in and since `myType` lives in the same namespace that the overloaded `operator<<` it gets founded and you get a correct string. But when you try to output a `vector` it tries to search for the overloaded `operator<<` by the same argument-dependent lookup rules and fails to do it since there are no overloaded operators in `std` namespace. So it falls back to the unqualified search which starts from the namespace where the call is made, hence it finds your stub `operator<<`

So in order to fix it you might have placed `operator<<` overloads to the `std` namespace(which is forbidden by the Standard) or remove your namespace — it will give the same effect.

You don't have to put everything out of the private namespace, though. It is enough to do something like this in the global namespace:

```
typedef char no;
typedef char yes[2];
template<typename T>
no operator<<(ostream const&, T const&);
```

Or, if it is possible, it is better to require the library users to put their overloads into the same namespaces where their classes live. It will not work with `std` members, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here.

The first is that something in the `has_insertion_operator<>` predicate is amiss.

I replaced it with this one...

```
template<class T>
struct has_insertion_operator
{
    template<class U>
    static auto test(U*p) -> decltype((std::declval<std::ostream>() << (*p)), void(), std::true_type());

    template<class U>
    static auto test(...) -> std::false_type;

    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test<T>(0))::value;
};
```

... which fixed that problem, and highlighted the next (which is perhaps more serious for you):

```
./stringify.cpp:73:12: error: call to function 'operator<<' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
    stream << in;
           ^
./stringify.cpp:100:37: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'stringify<std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > >' requested here
    vector<int> v(5);       cout << stringify(v) << endl; // prints "{?}"
                                    ^
./stringify.cpp:91:10: note: 'operator<<' should be declared prior to the call site
ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, const vector<T>&) { s << "vector<T>"; return s; }
         ^
1 error generated.
```

This is because the template function `operator<< <std::vector...>` is being referenced before it's defined.

once you move the definition of that up above the definition of stringify, everything works.

Final, note:

overloading `operator<<` for `std::vector` is a really bad idea. It will cause you all kinds of headaches later on.

> But I'm using c++98 and I want users to be able to supply their own overloads [specialisations]

Ok then, let's do it the easy (and more correct) way, which will work for all flavours of c++ and is going to cause no headaches due to invasion of the std namespace with illegal overloads:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


// define a template class emitter which by default simply calls operator<<
template<class T>
struct emitter
{
    emitter(const T& v) : _v(v) {}
    std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os) const {
        return os << _v;
    }
    const T& _v;
};

// emitter<>'s are streamable
template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const emitter<T>& e)
{
    return e(os);
}

// a factory function to generate the correct emitter
template<class T>
emitter<T> emit(const T& v)
{
    return emitter<T>(v);
}

// write one version of stringify in terms of emit<>()
template <class T>
std::string stringify(const T& in) {
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << emit(in);
    return stream.str();
}
// ======= OVERLOADS PROVIDED BY THE USER =======

template<typename T, typename T2>
struct myType { T data; T2 op; };

// user must provide an emitter for each custom type
template<typename T, typename T2>
struct emitter<myType<T, T2> >
{
    typedef myType<T, T2> value_type;
    emitter(const value_type& v) : _v(v) {}

    std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        return os << "myType";
    }
private:
    const value_type& _v;
};

// and for any std:: templates he wants to support
template<class V, class A>
struct emitter<std::vector<V, A> >
{
    typedef std::vector<V, A> value_type;
    emitter(const value_type& v) : _v(v) {}

    std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        return os << "vector<T, A>";
    }
private:
    const value_type& _v;
};

// test
int main() {
    myType<int, float> a;  std::cout << stringify(a) << std::endl; // prints "myType"
                           std::cout << stringify(6) << std::endl; // prints "6"
    std::vector<int> v(5); std::cout << stringify(v) << std::endl; // prints "vector<T, A>"

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I need this in C++98 - and also I need the overloads to be below ```stringify()``` - like it works currently with ```myType<>```

Comment: @onqtam on the first item, I guess some debugging will get you there. On the second, I can't help you. A template function cannot invoke a template function where the general form of the template does not yet exist. That's a language limitation.

Comment: "*A template function cannot invoke a template function where the general form of the template does not yet exist"* but OP asks about the discrepancy between `vector` and `myType`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: quote: "*For the `vector<>` type I get the default `{?}` stringification but I clearly want one of the overloads at the bottom to be called - **just like with** `myType<>`*", i.e. the compiler finds `operator<<` for `myType`, but it does not for `vector`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki oh, that'll be because he hasn't defined it in the right namespace. for ADL to work, the vector version of operator<< would need to be in namespace std. This is of course, illegal.

Comment: @onqtam updated. now works for all flavours of c++ and is more robust.